# Sortable drop to folder div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this(image).

[image]

The current behavior need to expand the folder(destination) to drag item to other folder.

Is it possible to auto expand the folder when I drag to the folder name ?

Here is my jquery look like:

```
$("#(phpgeneratedidforlist) div.item-list").sortable({items: "div.single-item",connectWith: "div.item-list"});
```

In case you want to see the html look like . http://pastebin.com/xwu1D90s

I also try this javascript(atleast help me open when I hover) still no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var isDown = false;   // Tracks status of mouse button

  $('body').mousedown(function() {
    isDown = true;      // When mouse goes down, set isDown to true
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    isDown = false;    // When mouse goes up, set isDown to false
  });

  $(".not-list").mouseenter(function(){
    if(isDown) {       
       $('.expand-button').trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: can you provide an example? How do you expand the folder?

Comment: click at the arrow icon

Comment: But with what functionality ? You just added an image, can you please provide a working example with your code?

Comment: that one handle by qcu.be . Im not sure which part of code to show you .

Comment: if it's an external library a link to an example where this is used would be helpfull

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: http://examples.qcu.be/assets/_core/php/examples/other_controls/jq_example.php combination sortable and Accordion